# Order an array according to another array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

Given I have two arrays, say:

```
a = [0.8, 0.2,0.1,20,1.5,5.8,12]

b = [2,1,3,1,2,2,3]
```

Now I want to order the entries in a according to the numbers in b, in that I would want to have all 1's first in the respective order, then the 2s, then the 3.., for these example arrays I would want to get the following:

```
c = [0.2,20,0.8,1.5,5.8,0.1,12]
```

How can I do that efficiently in MATLAB? Tks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, sort `b` and get the indices of `b` in the sorted matrix (the second output of `sort`). Since this is a stable sort, order will be preserved. Then use those indices in `a` to get the resulting array:

```
>> a = [0.8, 0.2,0.1,20,1.5,5.8,12];
>> b = [2,1,3,1,2,2,3];
>> [~,I]=sort(b)
I =

   2   4   1   5   6   3   7

>> a(I)
ans =

    0.20000   20.00000    0.80000    1.50000    5.80000    0.10000   12.00000
```

Comment: ah I didn't know that you can get the indices from the original matrix with sort, thanks!!